# WRSA.exe is throwing exitcode 2 while running through powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have Webroot installed in my machine and I wrote a powershell script to automate the silentscan of the specific location.

```
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $pinfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Webroot\WRSA.exe"
    $pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
    $pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
    $pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
    $pinfo.Arguments = "-silentscan=C:\Program files"
    $p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $p.StartInfo = $pinfo
    $p.Start() 
    $p.WaitForExit()
    $stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    $stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
    $exitcode = $p.ExitCode
    Write-Output $Exitcode
```

WRSA.exe file was executed properly, but as a result it is showing **2** as an Exit code. is it correct exit code or is there any issue in the script?

Answer (score 0):

Arguments that you pass are not escaped, try:

```
$pinfo.Arguments = ' -silentscan="C:\Program files" '
```

Comment: Hi, Still same issue.